# How do I split a string into two strings?

Tags: bash, string

I already know how to put `h4 h7 h8 h9 h7` into an array with space as delimiter, but after that I am trying to separate the `h` from the numbers to compare the numbers to each other.

How can I do split these in a bash script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=( h4 h7 h8 h9 h7 )

for thing in "${arr[@]}"; do
    num=${thing#?}
    printf 'The number in "%s" is %d\n' "$thing" "$num"
done
```

The variable expansion `${variable#pattern}` removes the shortest prefix string matching `pattern` from `$variable`.  The pattern `?` matches a single character.

The output will be

```
The number in "h4" is 4
The number in "h7" is 7
The number in "h8" is 8
The number in "h9" is 9
The number in "h7" is 7
```

Alternatively, to ignore remove the non-digit prefix regardless of how long it is, using `sed`,

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=( hello4 happy7 hobbit8 hulk9 hr-department7 )

for thing in "${arr[@]}"; do
    num=$( printf '%s\n' "$thing" | sed 's/^[^[:digit:]]*//' )
    printf 'The number in "%s" is %d\n' "$thing" "$num"
done
```

or, using regular expression matching of the digits at the end,

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=( hello4 happy7 hobbit8 hulk9 hr-department7 )

for thing in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$thing" =~ ([[:digit:]]+)$ ]]; then
        printf 'The number in "%s" is %d\n' "$thing" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: +1 Nice, Can you please explain this part: `printf 'The number in "%s" is %d\n' "$thing" "$num"` ?

Comment: @User123 It's a standard way of outputting a string containing variable data. `printf` takes a format string containing format specifiers (here `%s` for a string and `%d` for a decimal number).  The variable data is provided as the extra arguments, and `printf` will insert the data in the appropriate places in the format string. It works pretty much the same way as in most programming languages (C and Perl, for example).  See also [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: Thanks!! But if i use: `echo "The number in $thing is $num"` It'll also produce the same output. Is there any downfall in using like this?

Comment: @User123 Not if `$thing` contains escape sequences like `\n`.  I know it's very unlikely that _your_ data may use `\t`, `\n` etc., but other people's data may, and my answer is for anyone who reads it and has a similar problem.  Using `echo` in their code may do unexpected things depending on what their data actually is. `printf` guarantees more consistent output.  See [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: @User123 Sorry, I confused you with the person asking the question. Nevertheless...

Comment: Haha, Thanks for the explanation part and clearing my confusion :)